Week number within a month Calculated column
I have an Order date column, looking to add a calculated column that will show week number of that month.
For example,4th April 2024 should show Week 1, 29th April 2024 should show as Week 5.
Count should restart as Week 1 for next month. Week runs from Monday to Sunday.

Using the following calculate formula:
=INT(DAY(date)/7)+1

Output:


If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

How's going today? Do you have further concerns regarding this issue? Please feel free to talk with us if you have other questions. If the above info is helpful to this question, you can click "Accept Answer". Have a nice day!
